# Why databases doing delete and insert as updating a row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

If I know wrong please correct me. Databases doing delete and instert when we command to update a row. Can anyone tell me why or suggest me to read an artical?

Comment: Would you mind in explain it better? With some examples.

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to how a B-Tree index is updated? The DBMS cannot just change the key value, without moving it to a different location within the index structure.

Answer (score 2):

Some databases will use a delete and insert to implement update, and will have a log-structured file system so an update to a row leaves the old deleted row in its original position, and writes a new copy of the row somewhere else.

See http://blog.notdot.net/2009/12/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Log-structured-storage for a discussion of log-structured file systems for general use and for databases.

In terms of what systems use this, the above reference mentions:

> With me singing its praises so loudly, you may be wondering what
>   systems already use this algorithm. There are surprisingly few that
>   I'm aware of, but here's a few notable ones:
>
> 1. Although the original Berkeley DB uses a fairly standard architecture, the Java port, BDB-JE uses all of the components we just described.
> 2. CouchDB uses the system just described, except that instead of dividing logs into segments and garbage collecting them, it rewrites its entire database when enough stale data accumulates.
> 3. PostgreSQL uses MVCC, and its writeahead logs are structured so as to permit the incremental backup approach we described.
> 4. The App Engine datastore is based on Bigtable, which takes a different approach to on-disk storage, but the transactional layer
>      uses optimistic concurrency.

http://blogs.justonedatabase.com/tag/update-in-place/ also talks about the pros of appending using a log structure, rather than updating in place. It mentions:

> When we append updates rather than overwrite data we are able to keep
>   the old and consistent version of the data while the update is in
>   progress and this affords a robust recovery mechanism should the
>   update fail. We are able to easily watermark the updates and we can
>   choose to move that watermark only when we know that the updates have
>   been completed and successfully persisted in storage. Whereas with
>   update-in-place semantics we would have to write and retain the old
>   version in a separate log before the update took place to be able to
>   guarantee recovery from a failed update (assuming that a full recovery
>   from a database backup copy is a little too rudimentary for most
>   people).

Answer (score 2):

Most DBMSes will try to do an update in place without delete/insert.

But there might be some cases where this is needed due to the physical storage, e.g. your updating a clustered index doing a full table scan and the update will change the position of that record within the table, e.g.

```
update table set clusterindexcol = clusterindexcol + 10
```

When the record is moved to a different position within the physical table it might be updated a second time.

Or you're updating a Primary Key column for multiple rows, the easiest implementation to check for duplicates is delete/insert.